# How to change react-dates input css

Tags: css, reactjs, react-dates

I am using ***react-dates*** but I can't find any way of changing the css of the input field.
e.g. *border, background color* etc. since the regular css doesn't work with ***react-dates***.

```
<SingleDatePicker
    date={this.state.dateOfPurchase} 
    onDateChange={date => {
        this.setState({ dateOfPurchase: date })


    }} 
    focused={this.state.focused} 
    onFocusChange={({ focused }) => this.setState({ focused })}
    id="your_unique_id" 
    isOutsideRange={day => !isInclusivelyBeforeDay(day, moment())}
    numberOfMonths= "1"    
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom styling file and import that one rather than importing the bundled styling coming with the package. Like this:

```
// NOTE: the order of these styles DO matter

// Will edit everything selected including everything between a range of dates
.CalendarDay__selected_span {
  background: #82e0aa; //background
  color: white; //text
  border: 1px solid $light-red; //default styles include a border
}

// Will edit selected date or the endpoints of a range of dates
.CalendarDay__selected {
  background: $dark-red;
  color: white;
}

// Will edit when hovered over. _span style also has this property
.CalendarDay__selected:hover {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
}

// Will edit when the second date (end date) in a range of dates
// is not yet selected. Edits the dates between your mouse and said date
.CalendarDay__hovered_span:hover,
.CalendarDay__hovered_span {
  background: brown;
}
```

For more look the docs [here](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates).

Answer (score 0):

You can override specific classes.

```
.CalendarDay__selected_span {
  background: #82e0aa; //background
  color: white; //text
  border: 1px solid $light-red; //default styles include a border
}
```

[See document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dates#overriding-styles)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to create a component for encapsulating styles and connecting libraries styled-system and grid-styled

```
import {Box} from 'grid-styled'
import {themeGet} from 'styled-system'
```

and

```
const StyledWrapp = Box.extend`
    .DateRangePickerInput {
        border-radius: 4px;
   `;
```